# One Application with Two Databases

Tags: ios, core-data

My iPhone app currently uses Core Data to save Growth Entries created by the user. I'm trying to add a .sqlite file to the app that stores average growth data so that I can use Core Plot to show the user how their growth compares to the average.

- My app is working perfectly for storing and retrieving the user's data.
- I have written a utility app that creates a .sqlite file containing the average data
- I have copied the average growth data class files, the data model, and the .sqlite file into my main app.

Note: The average data does not need to be writable.

After much searching of Stack Overflow and countless Googles, I have come to the conclusion that what I want to do is implement two PersistentStoreCoordinators: one for the user entered data (readwrite), and one for the average data (readonly). Is that the best course?

If so, I don't know where to start. Currently, my Core Data Stack methods are in my AppDelegate.m (where Xcode put them). It feels like I should move them into a better place if I'm going to add much to them, but I don't know where that better place might be. And besides that, I don't know where I should start trying to add the new persistent store.

Thanks for the help!

Edit for clarification:
If my suggestion of creating two PersistentStores is the right route, how do I do that? If it's not the best route, what should I do?

Comment: this title made me think of a very awful meme

Comment: Fixed! Sorry about that.

Comment: This question/answer might be helpful: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947290/possible-to-use-two-separate-sqlite-databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Here is what I did:

- create a data model for the second database
- in the appDelegate method managedObjectModel:, add code to merge the two models (NSManagedObjectModel modelByMergingModels:)
- in the appDelegate method didFinishingLaunchingWithOptions:, add code to determine if the database already exists. If it does not exist, generate the data.

NOTE: you do not need to create the database before generating the data. That will be done for you automatically when you create a new entity.

The only downside for me is that I haven't found a way to prevent overwriting the data in the "second" database. But I'm still looking for a solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some starters:

If you plan on using different combinations of entities in different stores, you’ll need to add “configurations” to your MOM. See Core Data Programming Guide > Managed Object Models for info.

The normal place to keep the actual database is in the “application support directory,” which is in the User > Library > Application Support > NameOfYourApp. A string representing this path is what the automatically generated `applicationSupportDirectory` method returns. (Oops, you're asking about iOS. There, the `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method returns a path to the sandbox.)

The automatically generated `persistentStoreCoordinator` accessor is where the store is added. You could make different versions of it to add different stores, or you could add a property to the application delegate that you use to keep track of which store to work with. For example, instead of making a url to point to the default “storedata” file, you could do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @“nameOfStoreToAdd.sqlite”]];
```

In the `addPersistentStoreWithType` call, you’ll want to use `NSSQLiteStoreType`, rather than the default `NSXMLStoreType`. (If you ever get an NSUnderlyingException = "File at path does not appear to be a SQLite database.”, this is the issue.) And if you’ve set up different configurations for the MOM, you’ll want to add a string to identify the `configuration` for this store. Later, you might look into how to set up an options dictionary for the `options` parameter.

The automatically generated `managedObjectContext` is what calls the persistentStoreCoordinator accessor. So, again, you’ll need different versions of this or some property that is consulted to govern how the storeCoordinator accessor is called.

When you want to switch databases, you first save the current context, set it and the storeCoordinator to nil, then call the context accessor in such a way as to retrieve the other store. (Or you could probably keep multiple contexts open at the same time. Just be sure to set up separate properties to hold them and their storeCoordinators.)

The application delegate is accessible from any part of your app, just by calling `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`, so it makes sense to leave this code there. If it gets too long, you could always break it out to a category.

I’m no expert, so some of this may be a bit wobbly, but once you get started, you’ll probably have a better idea where to look for more detailed help.

Comment: Thanks.

I currently have two MOMs. Do I need to merge them? Or can I have one per store?

If I broke the Core Data code out of the app delegate, what would I be creating a category of?

Comment: (1) Can you have multiple MOMs at all? Not sure. Some quick googling suggests no; you can have multiple *versions* of a mom, to assist in migrating from one version to another, but I think you always have to merge the old version into the new one. (2) But the configurations feature should make that unnecessary. Simply put every kind of entity either store needs into your mom. Then set up configurations that check off only the entities needed for that particular store, that particular configuration. (3) Category on YourAppNameAppDelegate. See Apple doc "Categories and Extensions."

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup your [Persistent Store Coordinator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-SW4) to use multiple persistent stores. Take a look at defining [Configurations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW3) for your object model to control which model objects are stored in which persistent store.

Comment: Thanks. I read both of those documents before posting my question. They helped me come to the conclusion that I need multiple stores. What I need to know is how/where to create them.

Comment: The page you’re looking for can’t be found.